# Javascript wrap div in/remove anchor on hover

Tags: javascript

I have divs I need to wrap in an anchor tag with href="#" on hover and remove when the mouse leaves.

When you hover on ps_image it wrap ps_img with `<a href="#">DIV HERE</a>`
Then unwrap when not hovering.

```
<div class="ps_image">
    <div class="ps_img">
        <img src="albums/album1/thumb/thumb.jpg" alt="Dachshund Puppy Thumbnail"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

p.s. doesn't matter if it only wraps the the child div, but would be nice
     Basically I'm trying to get the cursor to be the index pointer, without it linking

Comment: Why not just wrap the IMG element?

Comment: well the img element is fine too... I just don't understand how to wrap/unwrap it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a terrible idea, but...

```
$('.ps_image').each(function() {
    var psImg = $(this).find('.ps_img'),
        a;
    $(this).hover(function() {
        a = psImg.wrap('<a href="#" />').parent();
    }, function() {
        a.children().unwrap();
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8zZY/).

**However**, you probably have a misunderstanding of CSS. If you want the image to create a cursor, add `cursor: pointer` to its CSS selector.